# Insert a bootstrap3 row that is full display height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, row

I've got a simple Bootstrap3 page, with some existing rows, and I want to insert a single new row that is full screen height.

What's the best (most clean & compatible) way to do this? I'd say using CSS3's new "height:100vh" would do the trick, but it still [doesn't seem to be supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) in quite some browsers.

Upon searching I came accross all sorts of tricks and wizardry, including using jquery, or plugins, but I wonder if there is just a simple css attribute or Bootstrap3 class that I can use for this?

Note that my page does not consist of just this one full-height row, I've got several dynamically sizes rows with random content, and now I want to insert one new row that has to be full screen height.

Answer (score 1):

```
height:100vh
```

Should do the trick like you said, IE 9 support it very well.

**EDIT :**
For android user then forget CSS use Javascript :

```
var h = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight; //the parent container or body
document.getElementById("my_100_percent_row").style.height = h + "px"; //the row that must have 100% height
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this particular case I'm especially targetting Android users (others as well, both desktop and mobile, but most of my visitors will be Android related) and I noticed that the Android Browser until 4.3 does not support this. Or is there an easy workaround for that?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this seems to work (although I'm using `window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.offsetHeight` as the display height). Even on IE8. However, if my window size changes, or e.g. if this page is viewed on a tablet which is rotated between landscape and portrait (thus the display height changes), this won't update accordingly. Would you know a better alternative than to use events or timers to check for this?